# sed - add new line with matched groups value

Tags: sed

I have input text with a pattern '([\w_]+TAG) = "\w+";', and if matched, then append a new line with matched group string like 'found \1'. for example:

input text:

```
abcTAG = "hello";
efgTAG = "world";
```

expected output:

```
abcTAG = "hello";
found abcTAG
efgTAG = "world";
found efgTAG
```

I try below sed command but not work:

```
sed -E '/(\w+TAG) = "\w+";/a found \1' a.txt
```

Current output:

```
abcTAG = "hello";
found 1
efgTAG = "world";
found 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the backreference `\1` in `a` command. Please try instead:

```
sed -E 's/(\w+TAG) = "\w+";/&\nfound \1/' a.txt
```

Output:

```
abcTAG = "hello";
found abcTAG
efgTAG = "world";
found efgTAG
```

Please note it assumes `GNU sed` which supports `\w` and `\n`.

**[Edit]**
If you want to match the line endings with the input file, please try:

```
sed -E 's/(\w+TAG) = "\w+";(\r?)/&\nfound \1\2/' a.txt
```

Comment: Great, currently use \n for new line, I would like it depends on input file type, e.g. if input file is \n format, then use \n, if input file is \r\n format, then use \r\n.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've updated my answer with another version according to your comment. Would you please try it?